# How do I iterate over a dictionary and return the key in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python with people's last names as the key and each key has multiple values linked to it. Is there a way to iterate over the dictionary using a for loop to search for a specific value and then return the key that the value is linked to?

```
for i in people:
      if people[i] == criteria: #people is the dictionary and criteria is just a string
            print dictKey #dictKey is just whatever the key is that the criteria matched element is linked to
```

There maybe multiple matches as well so I need to people to output multiple keys.

Comment: did you look at what `i` is?  It's a key.

Comment: I'm not looking for just the key though. I need to look at the data linked to each key and if there's a match to the search criteria, the program will return the keys for which matches were found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
print [key
          for people in peoples
          for key, value in people.items()
          if value == criteria]
```

This will print out all the keys for which the value matches the criteria. If `people` is the dictionary,

```
print [key
          for key, value in people.items()
          if value == criteria]
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be within the original for loop I created? Because when I try that, all that the program prints out is what appears to be an empty array. The output is: [] and that's it.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I forgot I commented out the section of my code that added more stuff to the dictionary so naturally it'd return empty data. Thanks though, your solution worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
for key, val in people.items():
    if val == criteria:
        print key
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a dictionary of lastnames and traits:

```
>>> people = {
    'jones': ['fast', 'smart'],
    'smith': ['slow', 'dumb'],
    'davis': ['slow', 'smart'],
}
```

A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) nicely finds all lastnames matching some criteria:

```
>>> criteria = 'slow'
>>> [lastname for (lastname, traits) in people.items() if criteria in traits]
['davis', 'smith']
```

However, if you're going to do many such lookups, it would be faster to build a [reverse dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_dictionary) that maps traits to a list of matching last names:

```
>>> traits = {}
>>> for lastname, traitlist in people.items():
        for trait in traitlist:
            traits.setdefault(trait, []).append(lastname)
```

Now, the criteria searches can be done quickly and elegantly:

```
>>> traits['slow']
['davis', 'smith']
>>> traits['fast']
['jones']
>>> traits['smart']
['jones', 'davis']
>>> traits['dumb']
['smith']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in people:
  if people[i] == criteria:
        print i
```

`i` is your key. That's how iterating over dictionary works. Remember, though, that if you want to print keys in any specific order - you need to keep results in a list and sort it before printing. Dictionaries don't keep their entries in any guaranteed order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
for key,value in people.items():
        if value == 'criteria':
                print key
```